# mongodb sending userid's in an array as a query and return the json object of the users present in collection

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of online users here goes its model

```
var SessionDetailSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    providerID: {
        type: String
    },

    firstName: {
        type: String
    },

    email: {
        type: String
    },

    status: {
        type: String
    }

},{ timestamps: true });

var sessionDetail = module.exports = mongoose.model('OnlineUser', SessionDetailSchema);
```

I am trying to send an array of providerID's so that I wanted to check the collection which all providerId's are present and return me those providerID details.
and this is what I tried

```
router.post('/sessiondetails:find', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.providerID)
        sessionDetail.find({ "providerID": { $in: req.body.providerID} }, function (err, users) {
            if (users) {
                console.log(users)
            } else {
                console.log("not there")
            }
        })
})
```

unfortunately, I am getting the only first providerid response for multiple times.

i am sending the array from the postman it looks like this

```
{
    "providerID":["1090867867720278", "104761648907225164100", "114316680403119099502", "103668441331122956874"]
}
```

can some help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: try `req.body.providerID.map(id => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id))`

Comment: By using $in you will get the docs from collection whose providerId match with your array, so if you are getting only first doc, there might be a condition where your providerIds don't match. Also, if you are getting same providerId multiple times, there might be a case if you have multiple entries for same providerId.

Comment: @Ankit Thank you .. actually, I figured it out the problem is with the database. corrected it and it now works fine.